# Acquiring a lock on a table to be reindexed?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-q, paperless

first of all, I assure you, I have googled for hours now. My main problem is that I'm trying to fix a corrupted database of the tool paperless-ngx that I'm using. I am an IT admin but I have no experience with SQL whatsoever.

I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR:  missing chunk number 0 for toast value 52399 in pg_toast_2619
```

Now every guide on the entire internet (I'm gonna post [this one for reference](https://gist.github.com/supix/80f9a6111dc954cf38ee99b9dedf187a)) on how to fix this tells me to REINDEX the table.

When I do this using

```
reindex (verbose) table django_q_task;
```

it keeps waiting indefinitely with this errormessage:

```
WARNING:  concurrent insert in progress within table "django_q_task"
```

I am positive that there is no write happening from paperless side, all containers except for the database container have been stopped. I tried locking the table using

```
lock table django_q_task in exclusive mode nowait;
```

but the error persists. I'm at the end of my wits. I beg of you, can someone provide me with detailed instructions for someone with no postgresql experience at all?

Comment: I think you have more corruption than can be fixed by a reindex.  The reindex has already acquired the lock it needs.  Which is why it is complaining about a situation that shouldn't be able to happen.  But this should not lead to an infinite loop or an infinite hang.  Is this message just shown once,  or repeatedly?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! 
WARNING:  concurrent insert in progress within table "django_q_task" appears once and then it does absolutely nothing. (as it seems, I mean, verbose should show me SOMETHING as output, shouldn't it?

Comment: I just restored from a full-backup of my paperless-instance from two weeks ago. Works fine now. I am sorry for whoever finds this in the future with the same problem!